# customizing visual studio 2019

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

I have to build a program without debugging information to analyze it using ADA reverse engineering. here are the instructions that I must do.

1-Turn off debugging symbols (turn off -g).

2-Turn off all optimizations.

3-Strip all symbols from the binary.

any help on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

These settings are all corresponding to project. For example C++ project:

**1)** Turn off debugging symbols (turn off -g).

- go to Properties\C/C++\General, and set “Debug Information Format” to None
- go to Properties\Linker\Debugging, and set “Generate Debug Info” to None
- go to Properties\Linker\Advanced, and set “Profile” to No

**2)** Turn off all optimizations.

**>** go to Properties\C/C++\Optimization, and set “Optimization” to Disabled

**3)** Strip all symbols from the binary.

**As far as I know**, the symbols are just saved into pdb file instead of binary, please refer more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019).